# Rest-Assured. Random "Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object" Error when running multiple test suites in Maven

Tags: java, maven, random, junit4, rest-assured

I have a couple of test suites using Rest-Assured, JUnitParams, and JUnit4, this suites share a @Test method that has this portion of code, the code randomly gets an item from the JSON response that has a "children_uuids" value in them:

```
            // Test case
            response = serviceCaller.call();

            Boolean success = response.then().extract().path("Success");
            assertTrue(success);

            // get random content data
            Integer contentAmmount = response.body().path("Contents.Contents.size()");
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(contentAmmount);
            while (response.body().path(
                    String.join("", "Contents.Contents[", Integer.toString(randomInt), "].children_uuids"))
                    .toString().isEmpty()) {
                randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(contentAmmount);
            }

            contentTitle = response.then().extract()
                    .path(String.join("", "Contents.Contents[", Integer.toString(randomInt), "].title"));
            contentUuid = response.then().extract()
                    .path(String.join("", "Contents.Contents[", Integer.toString(randomInt), "].uuid"));
            contentChildrenUuid = response.body().path(
                    String.join("", "Contents.Contents[", Integer.toString(randomInt), "].children_uuids.item[0]"));
            System.out.println(contentTitle + "#" + contentChildrenUuid);
```

The problem is, that if i run only one test suite with the command:

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestSuite01#testCase01
```

The test runs fine, but if i run all the suites with the command:

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestSuite*#testCase01
```

I get the following error randomly in some suites:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
Results :

Tests in error: 
  TestSuite01>ApiServiceCommon.testCase01:1023 » IllegalArgument
```

This is a fragment of the JSON Response I get:

```
    Response:
{
  "Contents": {
    "Title": "Disponible",
    "Count": "31",
    "Page": "1",
    ],
    "Contents": [
      {
        "uuid": "asdn359614nf3f",
        "categories": "Películas",
        "sub_categories": "",
        "audio_tracks": "en,es",
        "operators": "All",
        "children_ids": {},
        "children_uuids": {},
        "parent_ids": {},
        "parent_uuids": {},
        "tags": {
          "item": [
            "Work"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "uuid": "kgirnxfnwoer35",
        "categories": "Películas",
        "sub_categories": "",
        "audio_tracks": "en,es",
        "operators": "All",
        "children_ids": {},
        "children_uuids":  {
          "item": [
            "091e2e53-cfc9-44f0-b691-83cf57146912_ShutterIslandTrailerVO"
          ]
        },
        "parent_ids": {},
        "parent_uuids": {},
        "tags": {
          "item": [
            "Work"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I've found that the problem is the times when it returns an empty "children_uuids" field, I have tried the following without success:

```
            while (response.body()
                    .path(String.join("", "Contents.Contents[", Integer.toString(randomInt), "].children_uuids.item"))
                    .toString().equals(null)) {
                System.out.println(randomInt);
                randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(contentAmmount);
            }
```